# Ajuda Foreach stdClass

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

Bom dia :D Preciso de uma luz!

Preciso pegar todos os 'ids' dos usuarios de uma tabela e passar para outra tabela, mas qdo dou um foreach ele me retorna apenas 1 resultado como stdClass.

Segue o código:

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE nivel_usuario = 2");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($result as $items):            
            echo "<pre>";               
            print_r($items);
            echo "</pre>";
            die();
       endforeach;
```

**Resultado:**

```
stdClass Object
  (
     [usuario_id] => 7
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

A função die() encerra o script atual, geralmente é usado para tratamento de erros.

Talvez seja melhor ela acompanhar a query:

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE nivel_usuario = 2") or die();
```

**OU MELHOR**

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE nivel_usuario = 2");
    $stmt->execute() or die();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($result as $items):            
        echo "<pre>";               
        print_r($items);
        echo "</pre>";
   endforeach;
```

Confira na [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.die.php)

Comment: Eu coloco o die(); para encerrar o script....

Comment: Mas o foco é que eu não consigo pegar os id da tabela usuario e colocar em outra tabela... linha por linha

Answer (score 0):

O die() dentro do foreach, coloque ele fora que vai funcionar.